# Fortran Pardiso sparse matrix formatting issues

Tags: fortran, sparse-matrix, pardiso

I am currently writing some code which involves building a sparse matrix in Fortran and solving a simple AX=b linear system. To do this, I am using the Pardiso sparse matrix library, at the request of the project supervisors.

The code is split up into two parts. The first half builds the matrix and the right hand side, and the second half calls on Pardiso to solve that system. I *know* that the first half works, because exporting that data outside of Fortran and solving the system in Python yielded exactly the results expected. However, I cannot get Pardiso to work properly, mostly because I misunderstand the error messages it gives. The manual explains very little, and internet forums are sparsely (no pun intended) populated with Pardiso-related questions.

The settings I am using for Pardiso are as follows:

```
iparm(1)=0
iparm(2)=2
iparm(6)=0
iparm(10)=13
iparm(11)=1
iparm(13)=1
iparm(19)=0
iparm(21)=1
iparm(26)=1
iparm(52)=1
mtype = 11
iparm(3) = 1
solver=0
mtype=11
```

The errors I get are:

> error PARDISO  (sequence_ido,parameters ) error_num= 4 Input check:
>
> matrix_number_new 22 ido 32675 are incompatible

The manual or the internet give no indication as to what this means. `pardiso_chkmatrix` and `pardiso_printstats` don't spit out any errors, so I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say definitely what the problem is, but here is a hypothesis. The value of 32675 is suspiciously close to the maximum integer value that can be stored in a 2-byte variable (in C: "short int" type variable), which equals 32767. Apparently some internal arrays in Pardiso store integer values as "short int" (2 bytes) rather than "int"(4 bytes), for the sake of memory savings. As I said, that's a possibility only.